# Test to verify primitive local variables are thread safe

Tags: java, multithreading

I had written below code to increase version count

```
if ("Solution".equalsIgnoreCase(modelName)) {
    mainsolution.setSolutionVersion(oldsolution.getSolutionVersion() + 1);}
```

i doubt above piece of code mayn't give proper result in multithreaded environment so to test this below test code i had written

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

            service.execute(new NotThreadsafe());
        }

        ExecutorService service1 = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

            service1.execute(new Threadsafe());
        }

    }


}

class NotThreadsafe implements Runnable{
    int x = 1;
    public int incrementX() {
        x++;
        return x;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("not safe:"+incrementX());
    }
}

class Threadsafe implements Runnable{
    public int getTwoTimesTwo() {
        int x = 1;
        x++;
        return x;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("safe:"+getTwoTimesTwo());
    }
}
```

but i got 2 as output for both Threadsafe and NotThreadsafe.

Is something wrong i have written to test above post.

Comment: Primitive local variables are thread safe by specification. No need to test.

Comment: In both your Runnable classses, no other thread is operating on the variables. I don't know what your code is supposed to be demonstrating.

Comment: I am a little confused. How are you testing thread safety? I mean where is the shared resource. You are essentially passing a new instance of Runnable to each executor.

Comment: Supposing the code was modified to share a single instance of `NotThreadsafe`. You'd be very lucky to demonstrate a race with this few attempts and all that I/O.

Comment: The problem with race condition is that it's quite random as it depends on many factors. You could run a program a hundred times without issue as well as this same program could face the issue on each attempt.

Comment: Testing for "thread safety" is a hard problem. Even though a program may be guaranteed to work as expected when you write it according to certain rules, a program is _not_ guaranteed to misbehave if you break the rules. A program that contains a latent, thread-related defect might pass every test you can think of writing... on _your_ machine, and then it might fail when your customer runs it on some different machine, or under some different OS, or after they update their OS, or maybe just because their machine is running a different load of processes from yours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply cannot write a test to demonstrate the thread safety of a primitive local variable.

The only way a local variable can be shared with another thread is if you reference it in an anonymous class.

However, by doing this the local variable is required either to be final or effectively final, so it cannot be updated either in the "original" thread, or the anonymous class.

Therefore, all threads will see the up-to-date value of that variable. There is never a thread safety issue. The compiler guarantees it.